# How to check the progress of the rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have some data in the seeds.rb, which I would like to populate to a table. Inside the seeds.rb file, I am using create! methods, so that when something goes wrong I get an error message. But when I type `rake db:seed` I don't get any confirmation saying things like **"data loaded success"**. I mean, I have to go to rails db, and then check the table again. Which is fine, but I would like to know if there is a way to add the success message for rake db:seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your db/seed.rb, add the following in the bottom

```
puts "data loaded success"
```

Comment: Thanks richfisher, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can just add a puts at the bottom, like @richfisher said.

This isn't quite what you asked, but I usually want to know what's getting created when I run my seed.  But I want my seed file to be idempotent so I can run it, add some new stuff, and then run it again, only adding the new records.  This leads to a lot of conditionals around whether or not to print something out.

I ended up creating a function in my seed file that does `find_or_create_by!` and then checks if the object is newly created (`created_at` is less than a couple of seconds old).  If it's new, I puts a message:

```rb
def seed(model, attrs, message = nil)
  model.public_send(:find_or_create_by!, attrs).tap do |instance|
    log_created(instance, message)
  end
end

def log_created(instance, message = nil)
  return if instance.created_at < 2.seconds.ago
  message = message || instance&.name || instance.to_param
  puts "Created #{instance.class.name.downcase} - #{message}"
end

# then I use like this:
acme = seed(Project, name: "Acme App")

# it will print out name or `to_param` by default
# if I want to use a custom message:
widget = seed(Widget, { foo: "bar" }, "custom message")
```

This way when I run my `db:seed`, I either get output about created records, or no output, which means nothing got created.